# Choosing specific objects from a list and merging them together

Tags: r, list, dataframe, statistics

I have a list of 1000data frames saved as an RDS file under the name, say, Data1. How do I pick the first 50 or last 50 dat frames from Data1 and merge them together as one big dataframe?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific with what you want. For example, would you like the data frames to be combined by rows or columns?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I would like to combine by rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to combine the first 50 data frames from the list by row binding. This should do it:

```
data_frames <- Data1[c(1:50)]
do.call("rbind",data_frames)
```

Comment: Oh sweet, I can't believe I got stuck with something simple. Thanks a ton this fixed it!

Comment: We've all been there. You can accept the answer as correct if you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it.

```
# create empty list
data1 = list()

# create list with 1000 data frames
res = lapply(1:1000, function(x) { data1[x] = data.frame(a =runif(100), b= runif(100))})

# assign res to data 1
data1 = res

# create empty object
joined = NA

# bind first 50 dataframes
for(i in 1:50){
  joined = rbind(joined, data1[[i]])
}

# bind last 50 dataframes
for(i in 950:1000){
  joined = rbind(joined, data1[[i]])
}
```